# Displaying an interactive image in Android

Tags: android-layout, surfaceview, android-canvas

In my ANDROID application, I am trying to develop an interactive image. The image is made of several interconnected nodes. I would like to tap on two different nodes to get the shortest path between them. When the nodes are tapped, I want to draw an overlay on top of the image which indicates the shortest path between the tapped nodes. In addition to this, I would want to implement the animation of the path from source node to intermediate nodes and finally to the destination node.

I was trying to implement this in Surface View.
Any suggestions on how to get started with this would be really helpful. Any tutorials, sample code which I can use as a guidance would be great.

Comment: You'll probably have to start experimenting on your own a bit, in general the culture here is not very receptive to "I want *X*, how do I do it" questions. Do you know how to draw nodes? Do you know how to intercept touch events? I'd start with these things.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by creating your own surfaceview class that displays an image.

Make sure you implement SurfaceHolder.Callback  in your surfaceview class.

```
public class MySurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements
    SurfaceHolder.Callback {


@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    mthread.setRunning(false);

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }
}
```

You can use a thread to call draw methods and render the image. Make sure to use Canvas locks while implementing Threads.